# zRotation on object through a method - sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, function

Why can't I use zRotation on an object with an (id) reference? I may have structured this question wrong, in which case I'm sorry.

This is the code.

```
-(void)moveAlien:(id)alien :(CGPoint)startPos :(CGPoint)stopPos :(float) speed
{
    float katetX = startPos.x - stopPos.x;
    float katetY = startPos.y - stopPos.y;

    //
    alien.zRotation = atan(katetX/katetY); //This doesn't work
    //



    SKAction *moveAlien = [SKAction moveTo:stopPos duration:speed];
    [alien runAction:moveAlien];
}
```

- Property 'zRotation' not found on object of type '__strong id'

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work?

Comment: Great first post, welcome to the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `id` is the same as `NSObject*`. And `NSObject*` does not have a property named `zRotation`. You may want to cast the variable, something like:

```
((MyAlienClass *)alien).zRotation = atan(katetX/katetY);
```

or even better, make the parameter a little more specific:

```
-(void)moveAlien:(MyAlienClass *)alien :(CGPoint)startPos :(CGPoint)stopPos :(float) speed
```

**PS:**
in objectiveC you usually describe the parameters with the name of the functions, like this:

```
-(void)moveAlien:(MyAlienClass *)alien from:(CGPoint)startPos to:(CGPoint)stopPos withSpeed:(float)speed
```

because the call will look much better like this:

```
[this moveAlien:alien from:CGPointMake(0,0) to:CGPointMake(10,0) withSpeed:3.5]
```

than:

```
[this moveAlien:alien :CGPointMake(0,0) :CGPointMake(10,0) :3.5]
```